# Can i develop for tablet using the Android SDK Java in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use the Java Android SDK in Eclipse for mobile development, in which I have to choose different versions of Android.

Can I also develop for tablets that have android using the version already have for mobiles?

Comment: simply, you can, but you will have to create different layouts and drawables sizes to allow multiple screen resolutions.

Comment: but is it appropriate for that? or is there some other standard and more suitable software for that instead of eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse is recommended and supported tool for creating Android software, but you can implement ADK with Netbeans, IDEA or others. Eclipse is the easiest and most probable right way

Comment: Thank you for your words, realy helped me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse is the standard IDE for developing all Android applications, including phones and tablets.

If you have an application designed for phones and run it without changes on the tablet via Eclipse, it will run fine, although the UI may not be appropriate for the bigger size (ie Android will attempt to stretch the layouts to fill the screen, which could look strange).

You can specify [different layouts to use for different types of devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html).

In addition you should investigate [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). These allow you to manage lifecycles of child views independently of the parent activity, which is very helpful for tablet UIs.

Other than that development for tablets is just like development for phones.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) that addresses your needs.